# How to maximize shelf-life of freeze-dried food beyond 25 years? Can this exceed 100 years?

Tags: organic-chemistry, food-chemistry

Many manufacturers will sell and advertise emergency preparedness food packs to still taste "great" 25-30 years into the future (or at least maintain a consistent taste over this period). For instance, they will cook eggs, lasagna or vegetables (anything really), then place it into a freeze-drier unit, which eliminates the water via sublimation. They then place the food product into a mylar or aluminium pouch (sometimes polyurethane), insert an oxygen dissector pouch in it, then instruct the customer to store it in a cool (less than 16 degrees Celsius or 60 Fahrenheit) and dry environment for long term storage.

What process happens after 25-30 years which limits its shelf life? It is the accumulation of oxygen diffusing within the bag over time? It is the oxygen pouch that reaches it absorption limit? Is moisture sneaking in? Is the organic structure of the food break down due to normal thermodynamic forces over time (increase in entropy)?

What if one wanted to increase the shelf-life to say 50 years, maybe even 100 years. What food break down processes will be encountered as the limiting factor, that would need to be countered?

What other tricks (other than mylar pouch, oxygen desiccator pouch, freeze-drier) can I use to maximize the shelf-life in excess of 100 years?

Comment: In 50 years, 3D printed foods will be common, so all that is needed is feedstock and the printer recipe. Yum! ;-)

Comment: I'm not sure that the issue is technical rather than marketing/demand.

Comment: @JonCuster Are you suggesting that no changes are required to the formula employed by the manufacturers to achieve 100 years shelf-life. Thus, is it purely a marketing decision that they write 25 years instead of 100 years on the packaging?

Comment: I think oxygen will diffuse throught the foil into the bag and the food will oxidize.
In addition, as long as we are near room temperature, there can be thermal degredation.

What could you do to improve the stability? Thicker foil to decrease oxygen diffusion.  Create a Vacuum around the package which prevents oxygen from reaching the foil.
Store it at low temperatures to prevent thermal degradation. 
The global seed vault stores seed at -18°C for 50 years at least.
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Svalbard_Global_Seed_Vault

Comment: @Anon21 - no, I think there has been no need to push the technology (or prove an actual lifetime in excess of 25 years) since there is not sufficient demand. Canned food, stored under reasonable temperatures, is still good well past the date printed on the can.

Comment: @JonCuster I don't suppose, by any chance, that you would have any suggestion on how to "prove" (with hopefully a high degree of confidence) that some food, under some specified storage condition, could survive 100 years, without waiting 100 years?

Comment: @Anon21 - like other similar questions (semiconductor reliability, spacecraft, other high reliability applications), one has to do accelerated aging studies as well as proving that you are accelerating the right processes. That can take a lot of work.

Comment: @JonCuster So if I were to assume that 'everything has been taken care of' using a "new process" (vacuum, triple-thick aluminium foil, etc), then the only process remaining is likely to be thermal degradation of the food sample... then all one has to do is raise the temperature and measure which specific foods "self-detoriate" at which speeds and temperatures, then commit to only using those foods which are identified, by those tests, to last more than 100 years to prepare the meals? I cannot think of anything else than thermal degradation at this point - am I missing anything?